# Retrieve the inserted id Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hey guys i need a little help. All i want is to retrieve my member_id to pass it in the other table i tried to use the $this->db->insert_id(); but it returns to 0. But when i look up in the table the ID value is 8. How can i get the value of 8 in my other table? Because im trying to run two queries in one execution. Here’s my sample code.

```
$member = array(
                    'member_id' => null, 
                    'account_type' => $this->input->post('mem_type'),
                    'username' => strtolower($this->input->post('username')),
                    'account_type' => $this->input->post('mem_type'),
                    'lastname' => ucwords($this->input->post('lastname')),
                    'firstname' => ucwords($this->input->post('firstname')),
                    'middlename' => ucwords($this->input->post('middlename')),
                    'gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),
                    'email' => strtolower($this->input->post('email')),
                    'mobile_number' => $this->input->post('contact'),
                    'password' => md5($this->input->post('password')),
                    'upline' => $this->input->post('referral'),
                    'account_created' => date('Y-m-d h:i:s')
                );
                $member_insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();

                $id = $this->input->post('referral');

                //count the selected id in upline
                $this->db->like('upline',$id);
                $this->db->from('member');
                $query =  1 + $this->db->count_all_results();   

                $this->member = 0;

                if($query < $this->reglvl1){
                    $this->member = 1;
                }

                if($query < $this->reglvl2){
                    $this->member = 2;
                }

                if($query < $this->reglvl3){
                    $this->member = 3;
                }

                if($query < $this->reglvl4){
                    $this->member = 4;
                }

                if($query < $this->reglvl5){
                    $this->member = 5;
                }

                $insert_downline = array(
                    'down_id' => null,
                    'level' => $this->member,
                    'fkmember' => $id, //referral id
                    'downline' => $member_insert_id //member id
                    );

                return $this->db->insert('downline',$insert_downline);
                return $this->db->insert('member',$member);
```

And my other problem is when i inserted the data in the tables. It only inserted int the second table. Here's my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `member` (
    `member_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `account_type` ENUM('REGULAR','DUPLICATE','CORPORATE','ADVANCE') NOT NULL,
    `username` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    `lastname` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `firstname` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `middlename` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `gender` ENUM('Male','Female') NOT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `mobile_number` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `password` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `upline` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    `account_created` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`member_id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `username` (`username`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `mobile_number` (`mobile_number`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `email` (`email`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=3;

CREATE TABLE `downline` (
    `down_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `level` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `fkmember` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `downline` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`down_id`),
    INDEX `fkmember` (`fkmember`),
    CONSTRAINT `downline_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`fkmember`) REFERENCES `member` (`member_id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=3;
```

I want is to insert first the member. If the member has no reference id it will automaically add to the member and insert a value of 'none' in the upline field. The reference id comes from the people who referred the use to have a membership. And if the member has a reference id it also add to the member table and to the downline table as well. But the downline table will validate if what level is the user. I dont have a problem in the look up of level. My Problem is in my downline column. It always store to the value of 0 that comes from $this->db->inser_id().How can i get the right value? Please help me guys.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `$this->db->insert('member',$member);` call should probably be placed further up, since you then try and read the last inserted ID and use it in the `downline` table! Otherwise, when you call `$this->db->insert_id()`, nothing has actually been inserted yet, so there's nothing to read!

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be

EDIT:

```
$member_insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
```

This returns `id` only right after the query has been made to the database. I dont see where you've inserted records in member tables before `$member_insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();`. That is there is nothing being inserted that the insert_id can fetch.

if you want to get Last id that has been added previously, you can do like this.

```
$lastid=$this->db->query("SELECT MAX(member_id) FROM member");
```